# Makefile max load on remote server

Tags: makefile

we have a huge project with very time consuming sub-tasks running on Unix.  The whole make process runs multiple hours.  So building in parallel is essential for us.  The expensive jobs are preformed on a remote server via ssh.  Everything works fine.  But I'm afraid that accidentally a team member could forget to specify the number for the -j flag.  The --load-average flag uses the load on the local server so no matter how busy the remote server is it would generate hundreds of sub-tasks on the remote server which would slow down the entire company.  Please note that I don't have admin rights on either server.  We could also live with limiting the number of jobs (hardcoded).

Thanks a lot in Advance
 Karl

Comment: Pack all remote jobs in one single remote make invocation? It would then be the remote make that would control the remote load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For older make versions you can consider the following. That is not pure makefile way, but works.

**Solution**

```
ifneq (0,$(shell ps --pid $$PPID -o args= | grep --perl-regexp -c '^make.*-j(?!\s*[0-9]+\b)'))
  $(error You cannot use -j without specifying a number of jobs)
endif

# Or oneliner:
#$(if $(shell ps --pid $$PPID -o args= | grep --perl-regexp -c '^make.*-j(?!\s*[0-9]+\b)' | grep -v '^0$$'),$(error You cannot use -j without specifying a number of jobs))

# Below part just for testing
all a 1: ; @exit 0
```

**Testing**

```
$ make
$ make a
$ make 1
$ make -j1
$ make -j1 a
$ make -j1 1
$ make -j 1
$ make -j 1a
Makefile:6: *** You cannot use -j without specifying a number of jobs.  Stop.
$ make -j a
Makefile:6: *** You cannot use -j without specifying a number of jobs.  Stop.
$ make a -j
Makefile:6: *** You cannot use -j without specifying a number of jobs.  Stop.
$ make 1 -j a
Makefile:2: *** You cannot use -j without specifying a number of jobs.  Stop.
```

**How it works**

It is taking information from parent process (that is `make` process) using `ps` utility, and later filter out arguments using `grep` (regular expression is more or less: find `make` command with `-j` parameter that is not followed by a number).

Comment: Great idea, works like charme.  The only glitch that I had to solve was since I also invoke subsystems with: $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS)...  I put it in the next answer since quoting is not possible in comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU make 4.2 or better, you can check that the user didn't give a raw `-j` by looking at `MAKEFLAGS`:

```
ifeq (-j,$(filter -j,$(MAKEFLAGS)))
  $(error You cannot use -j without specifying a number of jobs)
endif
```

If you have an earlier version of GNU make you can do this by checking if both `-j` was given AND the jobserver is active:

```
ifneq (,$(filter -j,$(MAKEFLAGS)))
  ifneq (,$(filter --jobserver-%,$(MAKEFLAGS)))
    $(error You cannot use -j without specifying a number of jobs)
  endif
endif
```

(this version will work for newer versions as well).

It's possible this won't work with versions of GNU make <4.0; I didn't test it.

Comment: Hi, yes this would help but as of now we use make version 3.82 and it does not work there. jobserver is only added to $(MAKEFLAGS) when you specify a number.  We applied for a make upgrade but this may take a while.  Do you have any other idea for make < 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

Based on to the answer from Kuchara above I needed the following enhancement, since I call some subsystems with:

```
$(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) ...
```

and this will add the jobserver and remove the number from the -j flag in the subsystem:

```
yy:
   @echo yy mflags: $(MFLAGS)
   @echo yy ps: $(shell ps --pid $$PPID -o args=)
   $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) zz

zz:
   @echo zz mflags: $(MFLAGS)
   @echo zz ps: $(shell ps --pid $$PPID -o args=)
```

Testing:

```
make -j 3 yy

yy mflags: - --jobserver-fds=3,4 -j
yy ps: make -j 3 yy

zz mflags: -w --jobserver-fds=3,4 - --jobserver-fds=3,4 -j
zz ps: make - --jobserver-fds=3,4 -j zz
```

I needed to combine the answers from MadScientist and Kuchara:

```
ifneq (0,$(shell ps --pid $$PPID -o args= | grep --perl-regexp -c '^make.*-j(?!\s*[0-9]+\b)'))
  ifeq (0,$(shell ps --pid $$PPID -o args= | grep --perl-regexp -c '^make.*--jobserver'))
   $(error You cannot use -j without specifying a number of jobs)
 endif
endif
```

Thanks a lot again at both for your great ideas.

Comment: You could also enable that "-j test" just if you are in the first makefile (using `MAKELEVEL` variable). `MAKELEVEL` is described here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html  But that of course depends on your usecase. If you are allowed to run submakes individually, your solution looks better than one using `MAKELEVEL`.